# Android Eclipse SDK Hanging on `Android SDK Content Loader`

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, sdk, adt

Whenever I edit code or change things in my eclipse project and hit save; the program just freezes and refuses to load with the menu popping up saying `Android SDK Content Loader` with no progress ever being made...

Anyone else every run into this issue?

Comment: Happens to me all the time, I restart Eclipse and it usually goes away for a couple days. I would love a more permanent solution.

Comment: Yeah... Tried restarting without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you start working in Eclipse before it is fully initialized after start. Wait until the status in lower right corner has ended all activities before you do anything.

If happened, close Eclipse first. There is a remaining Eclipse process in Task Manager. Kill that task. Then go to your Android folder (in your USER) and delete the folder "cache" and the file "ddms.cfg".

Start Eclipse and wait until it is fully initialized.